# Using Delphi component under C++ Builder makes calls to a wrong function

Tags: function, delphi, components, c++builder, graphics32

I'm trying to use Graphics32 package. Graphics32 was compiled and installed without any issue.
When I try to execute (debug) following code under C++ Builder XE3

```
TBitmap32* bmp = new TBitmap32();
bmp->LoadFromFile("d:\\sample.bmp");//This calls SaveToStream instead of LoadFromFile
...
```

it calls another member function SaveToStream which I can trace into and step while debugging until AV rises.

I have never encountered such behavior before.
Is there any compiler directive I'm missing or some workaround to make proper function call?

**Update:** I use the Graphics32 source from SVN. Everything works good if I use code prior to [revision 2122](http://sourceforge.net/p/graphics32/code/2122/).

Comment: Sounds like a discrepancy between how the Delphi compiler generates the VTABLE entries and how the C++Builder compiler accesses them. Odd indeed, they are usually pretty good about staying in sync about that. On the other hand, the [Graphics32 website](http://graphics32.org) shows the last Graphics32 release was 2 years ago and does not officially support XE3 and later yet, so there could be an issue with the package files you compiled in XE3.

Comment: I use source from svn. Everything works good if I use code prior to revision 2122 [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/graphics32/code/2122/)

Comment: Well, when you do a diff between an earlier rev and the latest, is there anything different in the project files or class declarations?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, as we can see on the [diff page](http://sourceforge.net/p/graphics32/code/2122/) there are some minor changes in units. The only thing I suspect is new "class function" declaration.

Comment: You will likely have to take this issue up with the Graphics32 author(s).